# how to check a json property is empty or not in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've a sample response value like this

```
{{
  "transaction_order_line_items": [],
  "payments": [],
}}
```

In .Net core Razor page how to check the "payments" is empty or not

I tried this following way but it's not worked

```
 @if(@transaction.payments!=null)
 {
 }
```

As well tried

```
@if(@transaction.payments.Length==0)
```

it says RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'Length'

Please let me know how to check the value is empty or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JArray` does not expose a Length property, but it does expose both `HasValues` and `Count` properties that reveal whether or not the `JArray` contains child tokens.

You can change your check to the following:

```
@if (@transaction.payments.HasValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Json data is in `JObject` form, this could work:

```
@if(transaction["payments"] is JArray {Type: JTokenType.Array, Count: > 0} payments){
    @* do stuff with payments variable 
       but remember. Payments is essentialy an array of
       JToken objects. You need to use the proper syntax 
       to access them *@
}
```

If your JSON data is in object form. this could also work:

```
@* Using Linq *@

@if(transaction.payments.Any()} payments){
    @* do stuff with transaction.payments variable *@
}

@* Or using Count *@

@if(transaction.payments.Count > 0} payments){
    @* do stuff with transaction.payments variable *@
}
```